# regexp find all values between quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to push all values of strings inside quotation marks into an array.

```
Database = {
  "English": "forget password",
  "zh-CN": "忘记密码",
}
```

output should be

```
extractedStrings = ["English", "forget password", "zh-CN", "忘记密码"]
```

Comment: Is there a question here? If so you might want to show what you've attempted.

Comment: I want to ask for the regexp code to find all matches inside the qoutation mark... sorry I dont have a clue..

Comment: They all match don't they...? I don't know that regex is needed to determine that.

Comment: I want to extract the Database = { "English": "forget password", "zh-CN": "忘记密码", }

Comment: Don't use regexp for this. Among other problems with that approach, you'll have to deal with escaped quotes inside strings.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Object.entries` and `Array.prototype.concat` as follows

```
var extractedStrings = [].concat(...Object.entries(Database));
```

For Internet Exploder and Opera, you will need a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill) for `Object.entries`

Comment: Not supported in IE or Opera without a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill)

Comment: Is there any regexp to find all values inside the qoutes?

Comment: it's an **Object** - so no - perhaps you could use JSON.stringify and some judicious use of string.replace with a regexp - but that would probably end up with edge cases depending on your string values having `:` in them - if your strings are guaranteed never to have `:`, then, yes, JSON.stringify with  a bunch of replaces will work

Comment: This would be a good answer if you removed the last (regexp) part.

Comment: I only added it because OP asked if there was a RegExp solution - there is a caveat on using that method

Comment: This falls into the category of answering a question about how to pound a nail into your head by suggesting he use a hammer.

Comment: yes it does @torazaburo - your point is well made, I shall recommend he uses screws with a screwdriver instead :p ... actually, it's more akin to *answering a question about how to pound a nail into your head by suggesting he use a screwdriver*

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should loop over the object's keys and push the keys and values into an array. A little more compatible than using *Object.entries* and spread syntax.

```js
var database = { "English": "forget password", "zh-CN": "忘记密码", }

var keyValues = Object.keys(database).reduce(function(acc, key) {
  acc.push(key, database[key]);
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(keyValues)
```

You could also do a regular expression version to match on any character that isn't part of the JSON grammar. The following is a somewhat naive implementation, I think the above is better:

```js
var database = { "English": "forget password", "zh-CN": "忘记密码", }

console.log(JSON.stringify(database).match(/[^\":{},]+/g))
```

Comment: This would be a good answer if you removed the last part, which is neither robust nor advisable.

Comment: @torazaburo—yep, but the OP seems keen. :-/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = { "English": "forget password", "zh-CN": "忘记密码",};
var arr=[];
for(var p in obj){
  arr.push(p);
  arr.push(obj[p]);
}
console.info(arr);
```

you can try this .

Comment: You really should use a *hasOwnProperty* test with *for..in* here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Database = {
  "English": "forget password",
  "zh-CN": "忘记密码",
  "other-language": "embedded \"quotes\""
}


a = JSON.stringify(Database);
words = a.match(/"(.*?)"/g);

console.log(words);
```

Comment: nice!!! but ends up with `"Englidh"` etc - i.e the quotes are part of the resulting string

Comment: Try running this with an input such as `Database = { "English": "forgot \"password\""};`.